# Circle is to cylinder as ellipse is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, mathematics, analogy

What do you call the geometric shape obtained when you give an ellipse thickness? Or in other words, a circle is to a cylinder as an ellipse is to what?

Comment: The Q is based on a misconception. NARQ.

Answer (score 10):

A circle is to a cylinder as an ellipse is to a cylinder.  As noted in  [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cylinder#Noun),  a cylinder is

> A surface created by projecting a closed two-dimensional curve along an axis intersecting the plane of the curve.
>
> > When the two-dimensional curve is a circle, the cylinder is called a circular cylinder. When the axis is perpendicular to the plane of the curve, the cylinder is called a right cylinder. In non-mathematical usage, both right and circular are usually implied.

You might say that a circle is to a right circular cylinder as an  ellipse is to a right elliptical cylinder.

*[Ellipsoid](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ellipsoid#Noun)* is of course not the answer.  A circle is to a  [sphere](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sphere#Noun) as an  ellipse is to an ellipsoid.